# jQuery show function doesn't work on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, events

I'm having an issue with the jQuery `show()` function. My code works pretty well in FF. I have a combo calling an Ajax function on its change event, this function makes use in its `beforeSend` methods of `jQuery(selector).show()` in order to show a loader. I don't know what is wrong with the code or with the way that I'm using it. 
Does somebody see some kind of error in my code or has some knowledge of any problem using the `show()` function in Chrome?

Html code-

```
<select class="coor_select required" id="coor_dpto" name="coor_dpto">
            <option value="" >Departamento</option>
            <?php foreach ($departamentos as $dpto): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo (string) $dpto->codigo ?>" ><?php echo $dpto->nombre ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

jQuery trigger ajax function

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#coor_dpto', function() {
    var ciudades = get_ciudades_by_dpto('<?php echo $this->getAjaxUrl() ?>', '<?php echo $token; ?>', jQuery(this).val(), "#loaderCiudades");
    jQuery('#coor_ciudades_select_tpl_cont').html(template(ciudades));
});
```

Ajax function

```
function get_ciudades_by_dpto(ajaxurl, param_token, dpto,loader_selector) {
var loader = typeof loader_selector !== 'undefined' ? loader_selector : "#loader";  

console.log(loader);
var templateData = '';
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    async: false,
    data: {action: 'coor_ajax', functionaction: 'get_ciudades', token: param_token, cod_dpto: dpto},
    beforeSend: function( jqXHR) {
        //console.log('asdasd');
        jQuery(loader).show();
    },
    success: function(response) {

    },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
       // console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON);
        jQuery(loader).hide('hide');
        var $ciudades = jqXHR.responseJSON;
        var ciudades = [];
        for (var i in $ciudades) {
            ciudades.push({codigo: $ciudades[i].codigo, nombre: $ciudades[i].nombre});
        }

        templateData = {
            ciudades: ciudades
        };
    }
});
return templateData;
}
```

You can see this at: [coordinadora.spiderdigitalmarketing.com](http://coordinadora.spiderdigitalmarketing.com/), in the accordion at header, the first tab has the "Departamento" combo.

Comment: I can not see the Departamento select on your website...can you post the right url...thanks

Comment: Why don't you just show it before the ajax call and remove it when the call is complete?

Comment: Robert, the url it's ok. The combo is in the first tab of the accordion.

Gary, I tried, don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite my code a little and now it is working. However I don't know why Chrome was unable to execute the first code as expected. I think it is a matter of how many time took chrome to find the selector before made the ajax request.

HTML code -

```
<select class="coor_select required" id="coor_dpto" name="coor_dpto">
        <option value="" >Departamento</option>
        <?php foreach ($departamentos as $dpto): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo (string) $dpto->codigo ?>" ><?php echo $dpto->nombre ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

jQuery trigger ajax function -

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#coor_dpto', function() {
    var opciones={
        ajaxurl:'<?php echo $this->getAjaxUrl() ?>',
        token:'<?php echo $token; ?>',
        dpto:jQuery(this).val(),
        handletemplate:template,
        container:jQuery('#coor_ciudades_select_tpl_cont'),
        loader:jQuery("#loaderCiudades")
    };
    get_ciudades_by_dpto(opciones);
    //jQuery('#coor_ciudades_select_tpl_cont').html(template(ciudades));
});
```

Ajax function

```
function get_ciudades_by_dpto(opciones) {
var templateData = '';
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: opciones.ajaxurl,
    async: true,
    data: {action: 'coor_ajax', functionaction: 'get_ciudades', token: opciones.token, cod_dpto: opciones.dpto},
    beforeSend: function( jqXHR) {
        jQuery(opciones.loader).show();            
    },
    success: function(response) {
        //console.log(response);
        jQuery(opciones.loader).hide();
        var $ciudades = response;
        var ciudades = [];
        for (var i in $ciudades) {
            ciudades.push({codigo: $ciudades[i].codigo, nombre: $ciudades[i].nombre});
        }
        templateData = {
            ciudades: ciudades
        };            
       opciones.container.html(opciones.handletemplate(templateData)); 
    }

});
```

}

Comment: In case of somebody come here with some similar issue, in my particular case when the **async** option is false chrome doesn't show the loader. It made me think that chrome doesn't have time enough to find the selector and show it before send the ajax request, however I don't know how to prove it.